# Compiz makes CPU run at 100% when in suspend mode in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, compiz, suspend, cpu-load

Recently I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop. And I found that when I left my laptop suspend mode, the Compiz hold CPU at 100% all the time until the laptop woke up.

Can anyone tell me what is happening?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to AskUbuntu. The question is somewhat vague. Can you explain how you checked CPU usage when the computer has been suspended.

Comment: hi, mike.At first I just notice the sound that CPU worked too busy when suspend.Then I started a "top" command and waited for the notebook go into suspend and I find the "compiz" process hold CPU 100% all the time.Apologize for my pool English.:)

Answer (score 4):

What video card do you have?  What driver are you using?

There's a number of bugs that a Google search turns up.

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/771238
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/773564
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/969860

For the 2nd one, a possible solution is to disable the file watcher plugin in `ccsm`. However, this plugin is not enabled by default, so that solution may not apply.

For the 3rd one, a suggested workaround is to enable either the "Force full screen redraw" or "Vertical synchronization" options in `ccsm`.

Do any of those bugs seem related?

Comment: Hi, I have ATI radeon Mobility HD5650 on my notebook, using the driver provided in the "Additional drivers".The problems did not happen when I used ubuntu 11.10 last week.

Comment: I will have a look on the links you suggested.Thanks.

Comment: @Mikel The workaround in the 3rd bug worked for me by enable "Force full screen redraw"

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem on HP Pavilion dv6 with ATI Radeon HD5000 series card. It does seem to be the same as [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/969860).

The solution for me was as stated above to "Force full screen redraw" via ccsm and to follow the steps in the workaround 1 on the bug report itself.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issues with cpu usage because of compiz. My workaround was to switch session from Ubuntu to Ubuntu 2D.

[image: ubuntu 2d]

Comment: Why down-voted?

Comment: upvoted - think this was a useful suggestion though there may be better options available.  Downvoting without sharing useful suggestions is lame.